# Compare two arrays without sort them

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying solving a problem where i need to check if the arrays are same no matter how they are sorted i cannot use sorting because it add extra over head to time this function is taking in answering.

I am currently using  `array_diff_assoc`

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(3,2,1);

$result = array_diff_assoc($arr1,$arr2);

print_r($result);
```

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
But the above arrays are same!! The human way.

Any idea for comparing two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well interpreter is not human right ? ;)

Even if you do a simple `var_dump($arr1==$arr2)` on your existing array, it will return false.

This below code returns true !

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(2=>3,1=>2,0=>1);//position is same as yours., i've just set a key
var_dump($arr1==$arr2); //true
```

Comment: Why $arr2 = array(0=>3,1=>2,2=>1); dose not work.

Comment: It will definitely wont work. Since the arrangement of array differs with keys.